# cygwin.bat Disappeared from Windows7 Machine

Tags: cygwin

I was using cygwin for some testing, and at some point I needed to close the open window and reopen to start over.  When I clicked on the desktop shortcut I got a message that said 'cygwin.bat has changed or moved'.

Any idea what possibly could've happened and if so can it be recovered from?

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin.bat is created by cygwin `Setup`. 
Run `Setup` again to re-create it.